# Grouping By in java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to java Stream API and have a use case to solve using it.

```
Map<Object, ? extends Object> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.getX()
                                                            ,Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.getY()
                                                            ,Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.getZ()))));
```

Consider that x,y and z are the attributes of a given class. This works fine if we have the order of grouping (which attribute to consider first, second and so on...) predefined.

(In given piece of code attribute x is considered 1st, y 2nd and z 3rd).

Now, In my case, order of grouping is not predefined and may change at run time. So, at compile time i don't know what to pass in collect method.
I am looking for a solution by which I can read the config string and change grouping at run time.

Comment: What do you mean by "read the config string and change grouping at run time."?

Comment: ok, lets assume it is user defined- so if user defines groupingOrder = x,y,z it should be grouped as above, if another user defines it as y,x,z it should change accordingly .. (*groupingOrder is just the name I took for reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a helper method which builds your own `Collector` using given classification functions:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Map<?, ?>> multiGrouping(
                                                Function<? super T, ?>... classifiers) {
    Collector<T, ?, Map<?, ?>> result = null;
    for(int i=classifiers.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        Collector<?, ?, ?> next;
        if(result == null) {
            next = Collectors.groupingBy(classifiers[i]);
        } else {
            next = Collectors.groupingBy(classifiers[i], result);
        }
        result = (Collector<T, ?, Map<?, ?>>)next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage example:

```
Map<?, ?> map = Stream.of("abc", "def", "cd", "cfff")
                      .collect(multiGrouping(String::length, s -> s.charAt(0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `p` is of class `P`, you can define the order like this:

```
Function<P, Object> g1 = P::getX;
Function<P, Object> g2 = P::getX;
Function<P, Object> g3 = P::getX;
```

And then:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(g1,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(g2,
                          Collectors.groupingBy(g3))));
```

The g1, g2, g3 could also be defined using reflection to access a method/field at runtime based on the field/method's name.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, In that case do I need to define the order for all the attributes? I thought of constructing the "Collectors.groupingBy(..." as a String at run time based on config string, (like      **"list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(g1,               Collectors.groupingBy(g2,Collectors.groupingBy(g3))));"**                                                                        and then execute it using groovy, but it seems like current groovy version doesn't support lambda..